# image not displaying on the button

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

The image i imported is not displaying on the button. Any ideas why?

```
eye_img = PhotoImage(file="Eye.gif")
eye_img = eye_img.subsample(19)

show_password = Button(canvas, width = 31, image=eye_img, height = 17, bg = "#E2E6EF", relief = "flat", command = Show)
canvas_show_password = canvas.create_window(660, 355, window = show_password)
```

Here is a screenshot of the button display (invisible as the image isn't there).

https://gyazo.com/910e4a5ac539a463feca1955cc1d1abb

Comment: did you  do it in function ? See `Note` in doc [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) about bug which removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable (created in function).

Comment: Read [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424553/7414759)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research I discovered that this occurred because their was no reference added to the image. It was thus being removed from memory upon execution. Adding the following line of code solved the issue.

```
show_password.image = eye_img
```

To read up some more on this visit this website. http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm